# C char not working in if..else

Tags: c, if-statement, char, scanf

When I run the program no matter what I enter for `shape`, the final else statement is executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char shape = 'a';
    printf("What shape do you want?\nEnter 's' for a Square, 'b' for a Box, 't' for a Triangle\n");

    while (shape != 's' && shape != 'b' && shape != 't')
    {
        scanf_s(" %c", &shape);

        if (shape == 's')
        {
            printf("You entered %c", shape);
        }

        else if (shape == 'b')
        {
            printf("You entered %c", shape);
        }

        else if (shape == 't')
        {
            printf("you entered %c", shape);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Please enter 's' 'b' or 't'");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try removing the leading space on the format string.  scanf_s is not a good choice for reading a single character.  getchar is probably a better choice.

Comment: I don't know `C`, but `scanf_s(" %c", &shape);` is not capturing the input. BTW, your `while` will always be true.

Comment: @user3525735 : [Please avoid anything which is related to chating inside posts and comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/242800) (this include thanks and please...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf_s` requires the number of chars you want to read (hence the `_s`). Try `scanf(" %c", &shape, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a space character in parameter 1.

```
scanf_s(" %c", &shape);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `scanf_s(" %c", &shape);` with either `scanf_s(" %c", &shape, (size_t)1);` or `scanf(" %c", &shape);`.
You did not provide enough arguments.